# Is it a good idea to convert from a percentile GPA to a 4.0 scale GPA?

Tags: gpa

My school gives me my GPA as a percentage out of 100. If I have 91.55% overall, websites like [this](https://pages.collegeboard.org/how-to-convert-gpa-4.0-scale) and [this](https://blog.prepscholar.com/gpa-chart-conversion-to-4-0-scale) claim that this is equivalent to a 3.7 GPA. Is it then valid to write on my resume that I have a 3.7 GPA, or would this in some way be misleading or disadvantageous?

Furthermore, if I am able to raise this percentage to 93%, would it be valid to then report that I have a 4.0 GPA?

Comment: Are you converting high school grades like those pages suggest or college?

Comment: High school grades @AzorAhai

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To raise a 93% to a 4.0 is being slightly dishonest especially if you have a more specific metric. You can always list your GPA out of 100 -

```
GPA: 91.55/100
```

Most employers/colleges understand that not all schools have a grading system out of 4.0

Answer (score 1):

You should list your GPA EXACTLY as it is shown on the certificate / record as provided from the school.

If they don't understand or want confirmation they will contact you or the school and they can then do the conversion on their own terms if necessary.